# provide query string request mapping variable at class level

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to make spring boot application & swagger. Application is for REST service provide. I have made application running each page.
I have made a simple controller that have `RequestMapping("/group/user/contact")`.

Which is working fine.

I am trying to do something like `RequestMapping("/group/{type}/contact")` at class level.

So my question is that is it possible ?
If yes then just want some basic guidance. and if no then fine.

My all request working fine. All request came from `CORS` filter class.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, the handler method should look something like

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/group/{type}/contact")
public class ClassLevelPathVariableController {

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String classLevelMapping(@PathVariable String type) {
        return type;
    }

}
```

In this setup a GET request like e.g. `/group/test/contact` would be handled by the *classLevelMapping* method and the *type* variable will be populated with the value `"test"`

Comment: thank you for the answer but sorry still i don't understand what you want to say. will u elaborate it.

Comment: add a complete class example, should be more understandable now

Comment: and I want to trace each request before request came to here. based on it i am going to set the base database. suppose type is `teacher` then `teacher` database will be selected.

Comment: well that's a completely different question, and a much broader topic, so I advise you to post it as a separate question. Still, to provide some hints, you should implement spring mvc interceptor for tracking and for dynamic DB switchining you can lean on spring's AbstractRoutingDataSource http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/12/28/spring-3-2-5-abstractroutingdatasource-example/